# DataTables sort by two columns with different data types

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

There is a table with statistics containing two columns.
The first column is - name (string) and the second one is number of actions (number)
How can I make sure that the second column is the first one to be sorted? Given that the values have same names and also they are sorted alphabetically?

Here is my code:

```
$('#clickouts-table').DataTable({
  // eslint-disable-line new-cap
  processing: false,
  stateSave: true,
  responsive: true,
  iDisplayLength: 25,
  order: [[1, 'desc']],
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [0],
    orderData: [1, 1]
  }, {
    targets: [1],
    orderData: [1, 1]
  }],
  sDom: `<'row top-row'<'col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xxs-12'f><'col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xxs-12'l>
        <'col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-xxs-12 custom-button'>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>
        <'row'<'col-sm-12'<'table-bottom-toolbar clearfix'ip>>>`,
  columns: [
    { data: 'userName', name: 'userName' },
    { data: 'count', name: 'count' }
  ],
  data: data
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: is it jquery data table

Comment: Yes, this is jquery datatables

Comment: you already passed a parameter it will work what was the issue?

Comment: In this screenshot the problem will be more clear - https://yadi.sk/i/drde_qAN8Ei1Wg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your asking, but you can make column 0 sort as a String and 1 as a number like this:

```
columnDefs: [{
    targets: [0],
    orderData: [1, 0],
    type: "html"
  }, {
    targets: [1],
    orderData: [1, 0],
    type: "num"
  }],
```

See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type

Also, in case the column 1 numbers match, you should define column 0 as the secondary sorting option:

```
order: [[1, 'desc'], [0, 'asc']]
...
orderData: [1, 0]
```